# How to deserialize json object with no parent class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I'm trying and failing to write a program that will make an API call and then turn the returned items into objects that fit my model. Specifically I can't make it deserealize, and I suspect it has something to do with how the json is return compared to what my model looks like.

The data I'm trying to get looks like this;
https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?start_date=2022-03-01&end_date=2022-03-08&api_key=DEMO_KEY

As you can see, it consists of an array of items, but there is no name for the array items. When I paste this into the Get-model with Paste JSON as Classes, I get this;

```
public class GetApodItemsResult
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string copyright { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string explanation { get; set; }
    public string hdurl { get; set; }
    public string media_type { get; set; }
    public string service_version { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

My entire code works just fine up until I need to serialize the JSON with this line:

```
var responseObject = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<GetApodItemsResult>();
```

, where I get this message;
*System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to UnnamedSpaceProject.Models.GetApodItemsResult.*

Interestingly I know that the code works on a spotify api call, so the code really should work largely the same, which leads me to believe that the problem is with how the JSON is formatted.
How do I get around that? Because I don't see a way to have the root object contain an unnamed array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GetApodItemsResult` class is not a valid class to deserialize the content you get from server, the correct deserialization type will be `List<Class1>` or `Class1[]`

```cs
var responseObject = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Class1>>();
```

I recommend you to use more meaningful name instead of `Class1` you can name it `Apod` (acronym for *Astronomy Picture of the Day*)

##### Full working code:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
const string BaseUrl = @"https://api.nasa.gov/";
var response = await client.GetAsync($"{BaseUrl}planetary/apod?start_date=2022-03-01&end_date=2022-03-08&api_key=DEMO_KEY");

if ((response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK))
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine("field to fetch data from server");
}

var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var pictuersList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Apod>>(responseBody);

Console.WriteLine($"there is {pictuersList?.Count} apod downloaded successflly");
Console.WriteLine("done");


public class Apod
{
    [JsonPropertyName("copyright")]
    public string Copyright { get; set; } = "";
    [JsonPropertyName("date")]
    public string Date { get; set; } = "";
    [JsonPropertyName("explanation")]
    public string Explanation { get; set; } = "";
    [JsonPropertyName("hdurl")]
    public string Hdurl { get; set; } = "";
    [JsonPropertyName("media_type")]
    public string MediaType { get; set; } = "";
    [JsonPropertyName("service_version")]
    public string ServiceVersion { get; set; } = "";
    [JsonPropertyName("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "";
    [JsonPropertyName("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Comment: Wow, this was a much easier way of doing it than I have learned! I already had an Apod class from the "get a single date" function I wrote earlier, but for some reason the tutorials that I've seen have made the effort to go through a separate model based solely on the JSON input, and then transfer it to the actual object. Would there be any reason for that, unless you're looking to add properties to the object? Because doing it your way I could delete an entire model class and about 10 rows of code, so it seems like the obvious choice?

Answer (score 0):

The object your JSON containing is not some container with the array in it, it IS the array. So, the correct code would be like this:

```
var responseObject = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Class1[]>();
```

---

The correct JSON for **your** code would look like this:

```
{
    "Property1": [{
        "copyright": "Jeff DaiTWAN",
        "date": "2022-03-01",
        "url": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/2203/DuelingBands_Dai_960.jpg"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by my JSON, are you referring to the class names that are automatically created from the JSON file? Because class names can't have quotes, afaik.

Comment: @Peachy nvm, I made a mistake, there aren't any issues with quotes.